# Select if table exists in Apache Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive query which is of the format,

```
select . . . from table1 left join (select . . . from table2) on (some_condition)
```

The ***table2*** might not be present depending on the environment. So I would like to join if only table2 is present otherwise just ignore the subquery.

The below query returns the table_name if it exists,

```
show tables in {DB_NAME} like '{table_name}'
```

But I dont know how I can integrate this into my query to select only if it exists.

***Is there a way in hive query to check if a table exists before selecting.***

Appreciate any help

Note: I do not want to create the table if it doesn't exist.

Comment: If creating a dummy table, if not exists is not and option; then unfortunately it may not be achieved entirely using `Hive`. Hive command currently do not support programming features like `if condition`. I believe you should think on using shell script to execute hive scripts and check for the specific condition before execution. Please let me know, if that works.

Comment: Good point @gyan. I thought of that but the hive query has multiple subquery and nested queries. Trying to use shell to achieve that would complicate it more. I will try that if I dont find an alternate. Also, just wanted to check if there is any other option of doing it in hive

Comment: Welcome @Maverick. I believe breaking the queries into pieces and executing them using shell script conditionally makes it more manageable and portable.

Comment: @Maverick So what did you do?

Comment: @SuvarnaPattayil : I couldn't find a way to achieve it. I wrote different queries for different environment. (In my case I wanted to have a generic query for all environments)

Comment: @Maverick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was already mentioned in the comments that Hive does not support `if-else` construction, so if you want to have it, you'll have to borrow it from the languages like bash or [HPL/SQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59690156).

What I suggest here is the following construction:

1. Place the two versions of the query into a separate files as view definitions:

**view_ddl_if_exists.hql**:

```sql
create view if not exists target_view
as
select . . . from table1 left join (select . . . from table2) on (some_condition)
```

**view_ddl_if_not_exists.hql**:

```sql
create view if not exists target_view
as
select . . . from table1
```

2. Add shell script for detecting an actual view definition and copying to a predefined place:

**place_correct_view_source.sh**

```sh
if hive -S -e 'explain select 1 from table2' &>/dev/null; then
  cp view_ddl_if_exists.hql actual_view_ddl.hql
else 
  cp view_ddl_if_not_exists.hql actual_view_ddl.hql
fi
```

3. Add the following into your script/init script:

```sql
!bash place_correct_view_source.sh;
source actual_view_ddl.hql;
...
```

Voila! You've got the correct query in the view `target_view` and can use it in your scripts.