# How to use IF else statement outside hive select?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to execute select statement based on region check. If the region value is HK then the table should be created from temp.temp1, otherwise it has to create with temp.temp2.
eg:

```
**beeline -e "
if [ '$REGION' == 'HK' ]
then
Create table region as Select * from temp.temp1;
else
Create table region as Select * from temp.temp2;
fi**
"**
```

Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hive itself does not support `if-else` statements, there's [HPL/SQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59690156) procedural extension that may be useful in your case.

Though, I suggest you a bit different approach: if `$REGION` variable comes from outside of `beeline` and those tables' schemes match, you can union the results with the corresponding `where` case:

```sql
create table region as 
select * 
  from temp.temp1
 where '$REGION' == 'HK'
 union all 
select * 
  from temp.temp2
 where '$REGION' != 'HK'
```

Hive will build the execution plan and get rid of one of the union parts, so it won't affect the real execution time.

Comment: I just given the above statement as example. My requirement is something different, I need to add memory parameters specific to region.       beeline -e "  if [ '$REGION' == 'HK' ]
then
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx8g;
else
Not required.
fi                                                                                                                                                                and after that if close, i want to have my remaining hiveql code.    Hope u understand.

Comment: Then please refer to the first part of the answer: HPL/SQL is what you need.  
Also there's an option to use `if-else`s from bash with the help of `source` command, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62842567/9145106)

Comment: Yes- Hive it self doent support if-else statement. What i have implemented for now is  
if [ '$REGION' == 'HK' ]
then
beeline -e " Select * from temp.temp1; "
else
beeline -e " Select * from temp.temp2;"
fi**
"**

Answer (score 0):

Yes- Hive it self **doesn't support if-else** statement. What i have implemented for now is.

```
if [ '$REGION' == 'HK' ]
then
beeline -e " Select * from temp.temp1; "
else
beeline -e " Select * from temp.temp2;"
fi
"
```

I know this is repetitive but for now this is what we have implemented to execute queries of different regions/ blocks